# Qlikview - Data between dates; filter out data past or future data depending on selected date

Tags: charts, qlikview

I've seen threads where the document has Start Date and End Date "widgets" where users type in their dates, however, I'm looking for a dynamic solution, for example on the table below, when I select a date, say "1/1/2004", I only want to see active players (this would exclude Michael Jordan only).

Jersey# Name            RookieYr    RetirementYr    Average PPG
23  Michael Jordan  1/1/1984             1/1/2003   24
33  Scotty Pippen   1/1/1987             1/1/2008   15
1   Derrick Rose    1/1/2008             1/1/9999   16
25  Vince Carter    1/1/1998             1/1/9999   18

Answer (score 1):

The most flexible way is to IntervalMatch the RookieYr * RetireYr dates into a table of all dates. See http://qlikviewcookbook.com/recipes/download-info/count-days-in-a-transaction-using-intervalmatch/ for a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the interval match for your data. You'll can obviously create your calendar however you want.

```
STATS:
load * inline [
Jersey#, Name, RookieYr, RetirementYr, Average, PPG 
23, Michael Jordan, 1/1/1984, 1/1/2003, 24 
33, Scotty Pippen, 1/1/1987, 1/1/2008, 15 
1, Derrick Rose, 1/1/2008, 1/1/9999, 16 
25, Vince Carter, 1/1/1998, 1/1/9999, 18
];

let zDateMin=37000;
let zDateMax=40000;

DATES:
LOAD
    Date($(zDateMin) + IterNo() - 1) as [DATE],
    year( Date($(zDateMin) + IterNo() - 1)) as YEAR,
    month( Date($(zDateMin) + IterNo() - 1)) as MONTH
AUTOGENERATE 1
WHILE $(zDateMin)+IterNo()-1<= $(zDateMax);

INTERVAL:   
IntervalMatch (DATE) load RookieYr, RetirementYr resident STATS;

left join (DATES) load * resident INTERVAL; drop table INTERVAL;
```

There's not much to it you need to load 2 tables one with the start and end dates and one with the calendar dates then you interval match the date field to the start and end field and from there it will work the last join is just to tidy up a bit.

The result of all of that is this ctrl-t. Don't worry about the Syn key it is required to maintain the interval matching.

[image: Don't fear the SynKey]

Then you can have something like this.

[image: 01/01/2004]

Derrick Rose is also excluded since he had not started by 1/1/2004